# Combine multiple elements by class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the numeric values from some fields and add their value to a sum and put that sum value into another element.

It works nice if they are separate lines:

```
   var quantity0 = parseFloat($('#0').find('.cart-quantity-input').val());
   var quantity1 = parseFloat($('#1').find('.cart-quantity-input').val());
   var quantity2 = parseFloat($('#2').find('.cart-quantity-input').val());

   var totalQuantity = quantity0 + quantity1 + quantity2;
   $('.items-number').text(totalQuantity + ' items');
```

But when they are combined there must be something that I miss because it doesn't work:

```
 const totalQuantity = [...$('.cart-items .cart-quantity-input')]
    .map((subtotalElm) => Number(subtotalElm.textContent.val()))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  $('.items-number').text(totalQuantity + ' items');
```

There is one difference, instead of taking the ids (0,1,2) it takes the parent class `cart-items` but the error is not from there.

Comment: `textContent` has no `.val()` method; and if those are `input` elements, they don't have `textContent` either. You should do `Number(subtotalElm.value)`

Comment: Can you `...` a jQuery object?  Though i don't know why you would need to.  jQuery object have a map method.

Comment: @trincot, yes they are inputs

Comment: I agree with @trincot however would need to also see the html

Comment: So, `input` elements have no `textContent`. They have `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` elements have no `textContent` property, and chaining a `.val()` method will produce an exception.

As a side note: with `$.map` you avoid one extra iteration, and you can use unary `+` instead of `Number`

So:

```
const totalQuantity = $.map($('.cart-items .cart-quantity-input'), input => +input.value)
                       .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) comment:

```
 const totalQuantity = [...$('.cart-items .cart-quantity-input')]
    .map((subtotalElm) => Number(subtotalElm.value))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  $('.items-number').text(totalQuantity + ' items');
```

Comment: `$(<selector>).get()` does essentially the same thing as the `[...]` part.  It gets a basic array of the results.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to do the whole thing as a one-liner:

```js
$("#res").text($(".cart-items .cart-quantity-input").get().reduce((a,c)=>+c.value+a,0))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-items">
  <input name="a" class="cart-quantity-input" value="12"/> 
  <input name="b" class="cart-quantity-input" value="25"/> 
  <input name="c" class="cart-quantity-input" value="3"/> 
</div>
<div class="cart-items">
  <input name="d" class="cart-quantity-input" value="7"/> 
  <input name="f" class="cart-quantity-input" value="3"/> 
  <input name="f" class="cart-quantity-input" value="4"/> 
</div>
<div class="cart-items">
  <input name="g" class="cart-quantity-input" value="1"/> 
  <input name="h" class="cart-quantity-input" value="5"/> 
  <input name="i" class="cart-quantity-input" value="2"/> 
</div>
<div id="res"></div>
```